# javascript: Why this two different results?

Tags: javascript

in this code:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let minStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  console.log(minStr)
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < minStr.length; i++) {
    let tabWord = minStr[i].split('').splice(0, 1, minStr[i][0].toUpperCase());

    console.log(tabWord)

  }
  //console.log(minStr)
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

The result is:

[image]

and if I do that:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let minStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  console.log(minStr)
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < minStr.length; i++) {
    let tabWord = minStr[i].split('')

    tabWord.splice(0,1,minStr[i][0].toUpperCase());

    console.log(tabWord)

  }
  //console.log(minStr)
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

the result is:

[image]

Why this difference between both ?

Comment: `splice()` [returns an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value) of whatever you removed, so look at your code again. What do you do with the result of `.splice()` in both cases?

Comment: `splice()` returns the elements that were removed from the array. So in the first version you're setting `tabWord` to the removed elements, in the second version you're logging the array that had elements removed from it.